# Sharekit mail not working after call MPMoviePlayerViewController modalViewController ios 4.3

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, modalviewcontroller, sharekit

Im using sharekit for mail and twitter.

I have this code when click play button

```
CustomMediaPlayerViewController *mediaPlayer;mediaPlayer = [[CustomMediaPlayerViewController alloc]initWithItem:(PodcastRadio *)[itemList objectAtIndex:pageControl.currentPage]];
[mediaPlayer readyPlay];
[self presentModalViewController:mediaPlayer animated:YES];
```

After i press Done button, then i call sharekit mail, the mail cannot be clicked (can be scroll) and when i cancel it, the app crash.

This is how i call shkmail:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:contentTitle];
[[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:self];
[SHKMail shareItem:item];
```

If i do not call the mediaplayerViewController, the mail is working fine. This is only happen in iOS 4.3 in iOS 5 is working.What should i do with the sharekit or the mpmediaplayerviewController?

Comment: I found the answer it, i forget to put     [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; in my custom MPMoviePlayerViewController.